# If assembly is added to the GAC, do all assemblies it references also need to be added there too?

Tags: .net, gac, com+

**Background Info:**

I have two COM+ components on a remote server, based on .NET assemblies, one of which calls the other, which in turn calls a private assembly.

My chain of calls looks like this;

*Client Machine:*

Test Harness -> Initialises COM+ component "**TestFirst**" through Activator.CreateInstance(...), which routes via COM+ application proxy, then calls a method on the instance.

*Remote Server:*

**TestFirst** -> Method call from client initialises a COM+ component "**TestSecond**" through "new" keyword use, then calls a method on the instance.

**TestSecond** -> Calls a method on a class contained in a private assembly; "**TestThird**"

**The Problem:**

In order for the **TestSecond** to be called successfully, it seems that I have to install the assembly to the GAC. Otherwise, I get this error;

> Cannot load type 'TestSecond.TestSecond, TestSecond, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=...'.

OK, so I add TestSecond.dll to the GAC and then...

> Could not load file or assembly 'TestThird, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=...' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

The obvious answer here is to add TestThird to the GAC too, which does work, but I would prefer not to go down this road. This is just a proof of concept, and the actual project which follows this structure has many private assembly references and I would like to avoid adding them all to the GAC just so these COM+ components can see them.

Is there any alternative? Is there perhaps some way of associating a working directory with a GAC registered assembly?

**Note:** This question is tangentially related to another question I asked during the week, but I'm specifically focusing on the dependency resolving of GAC installed assemblies.

[COM+ component calling other COM+ components - "Cannot load type"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097815/com-component-calling-other-com-components-cannot-load-type/4097977#4097977)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make your assemblies load their dependent assemblies from whatever install path you choose:

http://www.chilkatsoft.com/p/p_502.asp

(No association with that company, their example just seemed relatively clear.)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I ended up going with a solution more specific to COM+, as described in my answer to my own question here; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097815/com-component-calling-other-com-components-cannot-load-type/ . I'll bookmark the above page for future reference though, cheers.