# COM+ (.NET) application referencing 3rd party assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, com+, dll-reference

I have a COM+ application that I wrote using C#.  I have the assembly strongly named & signed.  I want the application to use a library project & a 3rd party dll (log4net) but I don't want to place these in the GAC. The problem is that the COM+ application cannot locate the library dll & the log4net dll because they do not exist in the GAC.

I was reading another [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097815/com-component-calling-other-com-components-cannot-load-type) where it was advised to use the "Application Root Directory" along with the application.manifest file.  I tried this too, but now I get an error that looks like this:

> The COM+ Queued Components Player was unable to create an instance of a Queued Component. CPlayer BindToObject

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out the issue.  There was a issue with some of the underlying code in the application, but I was unable to debug it.  So, after commenting out the 'ServicedComponent' from the inheritance, I was able to debug my code, found the issue & fixed it.

The answer in [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097815/com-component-calling-other-com-components-cannot-load-type) actually works without registering dlls into GAC.